# Fully virtual Mongoose schema, held in memory and not persisted

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Can't find any docs or posts for this, which may indicate I'm trying to do something incorrect.

Is it possible to use a Mongoose schema that is entirely virtual, i.e. not persisted to the db?

I have a number of models, most of which are persisted to db, but would like to consistently include models that are only retained in memory, not persisted?

The closest I can come up with is along these lines, but it will still persist objects with only an id attribute in the database. Simplified here:

```
// access_token.js
var schema = mongoose.Schema({});
schema.virtual('token').get(function() {
    return 'abcde12345';
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('AccessToken', schema);
```

The idea in doing this is to abstract models so that the consuming part of the app does not need to be aware of whether a model is persisted to the database or only held in memory. Of course this could be achieved by creating the same object and methods as a plain object, but that approach would quickly become repetitive.

Comment: Could you return an object with aliases of the default Mongoose calls possibly?  With how MongoDB works I don't think it's possible to not get a record persisted to disk.  I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure [Mongoose's methods set it on the prototype,](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) which means if you change it, those changes would be persisted to the base Model. (Looking at the code, it seems it does at least.)

Comment: That seems like a good option, something like 'saveLocal' instead of 'save'. It appears you're right in regards to this affecting other models.

Answer (score 2):

You could override (monkey patch) the Mongoose methods which save data (e.g. `.save`) but I suspect what you are trying to do is difficult/impossible.

You could take a look at sift.js, which is a query library to do in-memory querying.

https://github.com/crcn/sift.js

Comment: there's an idea in overriding the methods the schema uses to persist to the database instance, will have a dig to see what is accessible

Answer (score 1):

You can set a [pre middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) for this model which always fails.

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    next(new Error('This can't be saved!');
});
```

So you will know when you are doing wrong.